# In Octopus, is it possible to upload a file to Octopus and then copy that to a file location in the target machine?

Tags: continuous-integration, octopus-deploy

I want make a file(.pfx in this case) available in a target file location (ie /etc/myFolder) before a particular Octopus process step runs.
Trying to use "Run a Script" step with a Bash script as my target is a Linux machine.

Is it possible to upload this file(.pfx) to Octopus and then refer that via a variable in the bash script and copy it into my target folder.

Comment: Do you need this file uploaded on each deploy or is it a stable artifact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to achieve this by,

- Adding the certificate (myCert.pfx) into Octopus>>Library>>Certificates.
- Assigning the certificate to a Octopus project variable(var1).

And, following Bash script in "Run a script" process step did the copying of myCert.pfx content into the target location.

```
original=$(get_octopusvariable "var1.RawOriginal")
echo $original | base64 -d > "/etc/myFolder/myCert.pfx"
```

Useful links:
https://octopus.com/docs/projects/variables/certificate-variables

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash, you can collect this file as an artifact in your script step with something like `new_octopusartifact /etc/myFolder file.txt`. This will grab file.txt from the target and copy it to the Octopus server. [This artifacts doc page](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/artifacts) goes into this process in some more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the response, What I would like to do is upload a file to Octopus server by my self first (doesn't want Octopus to collect it) and then I want Octopus to copy that file to a target file location